# How different cscfg files (local versus cloud) are used when cspkg is built using msbuild

Tags: azure, configuration, package

How different cscfg files (local versus cloud) are used when cspkg is built using msbuild? To deploy to different environments, do I need different packages or do I need different cscfg files? Also how csdef is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation mentions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710.aspx)

> The ServiceDefinition.csdef file contains the metadata that is
>   required by the Windows Azure environment for the requirements of your
>   application, including what roles it contains. This file also contains
>   configuration settings that apply to all instances. These
>   configuration settings can be read at runtime using the Windows Azure
>   Service Hosting Runtime API. This file cannot be updated while your
>   service is running in Windows Azure.
>
> **The ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file sets values for the configuration
>   settings defined in the service definition file** and specifies the
>   number of instances to run for each role. This file can be updated
>   while your service is running in Windows Azure.

Basically service definition defines the settings for your different roles. The service configuration files provide actual values for many of those settings. This is one of the way to achieve what [web.config transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) achieves for web project, but targeted towards Azure projects.

Hence the same package can be deployed at different location with different configuration using multiple cscfg and hence these files (cscfg) are not part of package that gets build.

Answer (score 1):

They are not included into the package, they are completely separate. You can rename the .cscfg file into .zip and just unpack it and see the contents - there's no .cscfg file in there. To deploy your service you need the package (.cspkg) that contains everything except settings and the right .cscfg that only contains settings. To deploy to several environments you can use several .cscfg file with the same package.

The .csdef file in not completely clear, it looks like it is included into the package and used to validate the package contents and the .cscfg file submitted with it (such that for example you don't have a setting declared in .csdef and not supplied in .cscfg). Anyway you don't have to carry it around.